# CSS Height:100% not working when HTML is displayed by PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have a container to center my web page using css:

```
#container{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

This perfectly displays the left and right borders from the top of the page to the bottom of the page, no problem.
However I have some HTML that is only displayed by PHP when the relevant $_GET is present, for example:

```
<body>
<div id="container">


<?php if($_GET['something'] == "something"){ ?>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Some HTML Here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Some HTML Here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</div><!--container end-->
</body>
```

When this html is displayed it pushes the content below it down as it should, however the left and right borders end part way up the page at the point where it would end should the html displayed by the PHP not be there.

[image]

Does anybody know why this is happening and if possible point me in a direction to get the border to continue down to the bottom of the page?

I have googled and googled but cant seem to find what I need.

Many Thanks

Comment: so, where is the `id="container"`? plus, the 1000px bit, check your monitor resolution size. I'd use a mix of width and max-width. This isn't a "php" related question btw.

Comment: Hi Fred, that div lies just within the <body></body> tags and surrounds everything else. Example: <body><div id="container">content</div></body>

Comment: what you posted in comments and in the question doesn't match. We need to know exactly how your code looks like.

Comment: your `<?php } ?>` seems to be in the wrong place. It's breaking up your closing `</div>` for the opening `<div id="container">`. That's why it's not working the way you want it to, while making sure the GET array does indeed have the value for it. Look at your HTML source and the css console; you'll see.

Comment: Please could you elaborate a little? The closing <?php } ?> is located directly after the div that I only want to be displayed if the GET is present.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. I tested your code with success given what you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, changed height:100% to min-height:100% in the CSS.

Its amazing how you spend hours searching then as soon as you post a question you find the solution. Nvm its here for others to see should they need it :)